# how to redirect with parameter # in the url address, I use laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

This is the view page along with the url parameter when new entering the menu : [url parameter when new entering the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0gpc.png)

Then, this is the url parameter when i press the other tab : [url paramater in tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41jzs.png)

Then, this is my controller

```
return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Success updated data');
```

The problem is when i successfully add data, it will always redirect to the first tab and the parameter # tabs-icons-text-2/ in the url address will disappear, thank you.

Comment: The server doesn't know about the # and its content. This is only generated by JS. You can save tab in session using ajax in your view, or use history push state.

Comment: can you give me a reference to look for it, thanks in advance

Comment: I just realised this today, but you can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php The common issue is that any value after # is not sent to the server.

Comment: Alright I'll try this case, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return redirect('/edit#tabs-icons-text-2/')

I mean you can specify the url you want

Comment: I need a dynamic redirect, because I have 5 tabs, thanks in advice

Comment: Are all the tabs using the same controller?

Comment: yea, i using same controller

Comment: can you send me the code how do you get to /edit#tabs-icons-text-2/

Comment: I need a little more info to help you

Comment: sorry I forgot, I did use the same controller but the method was different

Comment: how to tuck # in return?

Comment: here my code to get /edit#tabs-icons-text-2/ : https://pastebin.com/s8X3nRh7